# Como accesar desde dos campos de un modelo con foreign key a otro modelo django

Tags: django

Saludos amigos expertos en ORM Django. Tengo una tabla de ACCIONISTAS, en la tabla o modelo ACCIONES deben constar una persona de los ACCIONISTAS como titular, hasta ahi todo bien. El inconveniente surge cuando en el mismo registro de ACCIONES debe constar un CO-ACCIONISTA, que puede ser cualquier otro ACCIONISTAS diferente al titular. Trato de relacionar como detallo en el grafico, pero me da error. Agradecería, por favor ayudarme al respecto.

class Accionista(models.Model):

```
axi_frsname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name ', max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
axi_midname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Midle name ', max_length=15)
axi_lasname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last name ', max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)
axi_fechnac = models.DateField(verbose_name='Birdh date ')
```

class Acciones(models.Model):

```
acc_idaxion = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
acc_fechacc = models.DateField('Fecha de Compra', null=True, blank=True)
acc_empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
acc_titular = models.ForeignKey(Accionista, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Titular', null=True, blank=True)
acc_cotitul = models.ForeignKey(Accionista, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Co-Titular', null=True, blank=True)
```

ERRORS:
accionistas.Acciones.acc_cotitul: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Accionista.acciones_set' for 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_cotitul' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_titular'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_cotitul' or 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_titular'.
accionistas.Acciones.acc_titular: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Accionista.acciones_set' for 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_titular' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_cotitul'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_titular' or 'accionistas.Acciones.acc_cotitul'.

Comment: Muchas gracias Marce, por tu recomendacion.

Comment: Para eso estamos maestro!.

Comment: Saludos. Por si le sirve a alguien, la solucion es sensilla, y la encontre en este link.  https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/django/django-reverse-foreign-key/

Comment: Hola Luis, sería bueno que pusieras tu propia respuesta, y la marcaras como aceptada, de esa forma podrás ayudar a otros (aunque se caiga el link) y tal vez recibas algún puntito de reputación...

Comment: Gracias Marce, por tu ilustracion, perdón mi novatada en stack overflow. Haré lo que recomiendas.

Comment: Nada por lo que disculparte, todos "nacemos" novatos.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder relacionar con 2 forignkey desde un modelo a otro modelo, la solucion que encontre fue poner a cada uno de los campos relacionados el siguiente atributo y con el la sintaxis expuesta, ejemplo: related_name = "acc_cotitulOf".

class Acciones(models.Model):

```
acc_idaxion = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
acc_fechacc = models.DateField('Fecha de Compra', null=True, blank=True)
acc_empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
acc_titular = models.ForeignKey(Accionista, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Titular', null=True, blank=True, related_name = "acc_titularOf")
acc_cotitul = models.ForeignKey(Accionista, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Co-Titular', null=True, blank=True, related_name = "acc_cotitulOf")
```